# Sample Data in Cosmos (Return every 3rd data point)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are looking to pull a few parameters off a few thousand cosmos documents.  Arrange these and return them to the client for graphing.
The trouble is the number of points quickly gets into the 10s of 1000s which is much more resolution that the front end needs to spot trends.  It's also SLOW.
While I can easily return all the data to the API and then sample the data there, it would seem to be more efficient to just skip every 3rd data point or so.

Is there a way to do something like .Skip(x => x % 3 == 0) in cosmos?

Comment: If the `id` property is a GUID, you could try filtering on some set of prefixes, like starts with 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 1):

It would be doable in a stored procedure (don't include any rows numbers not divisible by the sampling frequency in the results).

There (looking at the docs) does not seem to be any ranking functions (not even a `row_number()`) that could do it in pure SQL.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Ahh the hard to troubleshoot world of JavaScript Cosmos Stored Procedures.

Comment: Just remember that Cosmos DB stored procedures are scoped to a single partition. Plus, the stored procedure would still need to retrieve data and then do its own sampling, since there is no built-in sampling function. Definitely would have lower bandwidth consumption back to the client but... no difference in data retrieval from a query.